# Jersey (+jackson) serialization

Tags: servlets, jackson, java-ee-7, jersey-2.0

I am using Jersey framework, with com.fasterxml.jackson as default serializer. I am trying to return json object with specified root name. e.g.:

```
{
  "rootName": {
                "key":"value"
              }
}
```

The question is how to enable root-level wrapping so I could make use of @JsonRootName annotation?

For now I am using rootName class wrapper to get what I need however I believe there is some more generic setting somewhere... wrapping object into another wrapper object just to get its root name in output seems not to be the best solution for me. If you could point me to better solution would be great.

Thanks for help,
PP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make use of the `@JsonRootName` annotation you need to enable the `SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE` and/or `DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE` features. Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonWrapped {

    final static String JSON = "{\n" +
            "  \"rootName\": {\n" +
            "                \"key\":\"value\"\n" +
            "              }\n" +
            "}";

    @JsonRootName("rootName")
    public static class Thing {
        public final String key;

        @JsonCreator
        public Thing(@JsonProperty("key") String key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Thing{" +
                    "key='" + key + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
        mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new Thing("value")));
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(JSON, Thing.class));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"rootName":{"key":"value"}}
Thing{key='value'}
```

To make it work under JAX-RS implementation you need to customize [the Jackson JAX-RS JSON provider](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers). There are few ways you could achieve this. One option is to register a context resolver for the object mapper as [mentioned here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQJaxRs). Another option to annotate resource methods with `@JacksonFeatures` annotation as follows:

```
@GET
@JacksonFeatures(serializationEnable = SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE,
        deserializationEnable = DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE)
public Thing resourceMethod() {
    ...    
}
```